# How can I create a complete local entity from a ParseObject?

Tags: java, android, parse-platform, parse-server

Up until now I've just been using the Parse SDK to query objects directly and then retrieve their properties, i.e. `postObject.getString("bodyText")`, `postObject.getList("likedBy")`, etc.

Let's take a class with the following Parse columns (via the Dashboard):

- text (String)
- image (ParseFile)
- rating (Number)

---

- lastReplyUpdatedAt (Date)
- author (Pointer<_User>)
- poll (Pointer< Poll >) --- assuming that pointers are different for User and generic classes?
- likedBy (Array)
- isPinned (Boolean)

I know how to retrieve Strings, Ints, and ParseFiles, but what about Pointers, Dates, Arrays and Booleans? What do variable declarations and mutators/accessors look like in those cases?

```
@ParseClassName("Post")
public class Post extends ParseObject {

    public Post() {

    }

    private String text;
    private ParseFile image;
    private int rating;

    public String getText() {
        return getString("text");
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    public ParseFile getImage() {
        return getParseFile("image");
    }

    public void setImage(ParseFile image) {
        this.image = image;
    }

    public Int getRating() {
        return getInt("rating");
    }

    public void setRating(Int rating) {
        this.rating = rating;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you asking how to create a constructor ? What's your question exactly ?

Comment: Ah, sorry. I was asking what the mutators/accessors looked like in a custom ParseObject entity for certain field types, i.e. Arrays, Dates and Pointers in particular.

Comment: For arrays you can have something like `List<Type> getMyList()`, for date it can be `Date getDate()` or `String getDate()` depending on what you use. What do you mean by Pointers ? Is it a custom class ? Or are you talking about object pointers ?

Comment: Yeah the pointer would point to another Class in parse. For example, a post may have an "author". Would you use ``private ParseObject author;`` and ``getParseObject()``?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comments are not made for answer, so I'll post it here with a proper example for you to understand.
Here's a simple class.

```
public class A {
    private int number;

    public A(int value){
        this.number = value;
    }
    public void setNumber(int value){
        this.number = value;
    }
    public int getNumber(){
        return this.number();
    }
}
```

And here s a more complete class.

```
public class B{
    private A pointerToA;
    private boolean isAnExample;
    private List<String> myList;
    private Date myDate;
```

It is completely right to have accessors for each of this field. And their synxtaxes is no different from "classic" accessors such as `getNumber()` in class B.

```
    public A getPointerToA(){
        return this.pointerToA;
    }
    public List<String> getMyList(){
        return this.myList;
    }
    public boolean isAnExample(){
        return this.isAnExample;
    }
    public Date getMyDate(){
         return this.myDate;
    }
```

You can also have "classic" setters for each of these fields, depending on what you're tryign to do.

```
   public setIsAnExample(boolean bool){
       this.isAnExample = bool;
   }
   ...
```